# return variable undefined in jQuery $.post sent by a cfc

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I am using `$.post()` to send a json to my cfc, which updates some records.  I am not returning a json back to the calling page, I am just returning the contents of a variable that I am setting in the cfc.  Based on the value of that variable, the update was/was not successful.  I cannot seem to get at the contents of the variable.  I just started using jQuery, so I think I'm doing it right, but apparently not.

the jQuery:

```
$("#edit_button").click(function(){
    if(theArray.length > 0){
        theJson = JSON.stingify(theArray);
        $.post("cfcs/fund_profile.cfc",{
            method:"updateProfile",
            data:theJson,
            dataType:"text"
            success:function(response){alert(response);}
        });
   }
});
```

I'm not going to post the whole cfc, just the important part.

I am just returning a string.

```
<cffunction name="updateProfile" ...>
    ...

    <cfif message neq ''>
        <cfreturn message>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset message = "success">         
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn message>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: FYI you are not sending JSON to cfc, you are sending a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$.post` incorrectly. That looks like a mish-mash of `$.ajax` and `$.post`. Your call should resemble this:

```
$.post("cfcs/fund_profile.cfc",{ method: "updateProfile", data: theJson}, 
    function(response) {
       alert(response);
    }, 
"text");
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @karmin79 That did the trick.  I kept looking that the jquery api reference, and I had a feeling I was doing something wrong, but I couldn't decipher what.  Thanks.